# Averageif and Offset Function in Excel to get a Rolling Average

Tags: excel, offset, moving-average

I have a bunch of sequential rows and I'm trying to average the last 90 based on a criteria. The average needs to be in a single cell, rather than a column that calculates a running average. I figured out how to calculate an average for the last 90 rows, but I am not able to correctly add the if function to meet the criteria prior to averaging.

Data:

```
sale type (b)        Data(c)      Rownumber (E) 
a                     45             1
b                     35             2 
c                     36             3 
c                     56             93
```

Here is the average function that's working correctly `AVERAGE(OFFSET(E2,COUNTA(E:E)-1,-2,-90)).`

Here is the `AVERAGEIF` function that I'm trying to run that is giving incorrect data:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B:B,I15,OFFSET(E2,COUNTA(E:E)-1,-2,-90))
```

`I15` cell in this case, is the sale type that I am trying to match.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In your example the sales type is datatype of string  and the average you want is datatype of numbers, its not logical to do the that kind of logic test.

Comment: I want to average column c (data) based on sales type.

Answer (score 1):

```
=AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(B2,COUNTA(E:E)-2,0,-90),$I$15,OFFSET(C2,COUNTA(E:E)-2,0,-90))
```

first: you need to "-2", not "-1" from your row, you're not getting the last 90 with -1 .. (test it by changing a record in data to "999" at the outskirts. You'll see it pick up that value when the AVG changes dramatically.)

second: your  and  range have to match .. heights anyway. So use the same offset formula in both.

To slightly optimize this, you could calc that "COUNTA(E:E)-2" in another column, name it, then just reference it in both cases (that way Excel only calcs it once, not twice). ;)

Also, if the I15 cell is a single cell, you might want to $I$15 it to be safe. I don't think this matters in this case, just a habit of doing that to single, isolated cells that aren't part of a range :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm afraid I wasn't clear with the issue. The formula you provided seems calculate the average for any row number less than 90. However, I need the average to go back 90 rows only. For example, if I enter row number 1 after row number 95, row number 1 should not be included in the calculation since the formula should tell it to go back to row 5 (95-90). Currently, if I do this, the formula still counts the result with row # 1.

Comment: ahh, I see .. take a look at Barry's response then ... that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have row numbers (of the data) in column E you could use `AVERAGEIFS` and just use another criteria based on column E, like this:

`=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,B:B,I15,E:E,">"&MAX(E:E)-90)`